# C# Create a function scope

Tags: c#, scope

I would like to create a scope object that act similar to transactionscope.

```
public void MyOperation ()
{
using(Scope s = new Scope())
{

Function1();
Function2();


}
}
```

Function1 and function2 are in the scope and they can know evertyhing about the scope variable and it can also generate an unique id of the scope.

It is exactly like transactionscope, but I don't wanna get my sql lock down.

Note that static variable is not a solution since it is running in IIS

Can somebody help me on that?

Comment: I wrote an [evil version of that](https://gist.github.com/2037478).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `[ThreadStatic]` static field.
If you're *only* running in ASP.Net, you should probably use `HttpContext.Current.Items` instead.

Comment: sadly, it is a com object running on iis.  THreadstatic cannot be used because IIS will resuse thread.

Comment: @KennethLam: Huh? Just clear the `[ThreadStatic]` field in `Dispose()`. It will work fine.